# Child .read rules in Firebase database not working as expected

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, rules

Imagine the following security rules for a node called asd in Firebase database.

```
"asd": {
      ".write": false,
      "$eid": {
        "prop1" : {".read": false},
        "prop2" : {".read": false},
        "prop3" : {".read": true}
      }
    }
```

When using firebase to query the `asd` node, I was expecting it to return only `prop3`. But, in fact, it is not returning anything. And from what I read at the documentation, it seems this is acting as expected.

So, my question is, with such a database structure, how to define the rules so that when I query the database I only get `prop3` back?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the answer @AL.

Comment: It seems I'll have to change my DB structure. Didn't want to do that, but looks like I can't escape.

Comment: Credit goes to @MatthewBerg. He's the one who found it. ;)

Comment: Thank you @MatthewBerg! And you too @AL. 
By the way, I added another question. If you would like to take a look: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711176/can-i-use-wildcard-to-build-paths-when-getting-references-of-firebase-database).