# Can I use wildcard to build paths when getting references of firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have the following database structure in firebase:

```
{
    level1 : {
        0: {
            prop1: {},
            prop2: {}
        },
        1: {
            prop1: {},
            prop2: {}
        },
        2: {
            prop1: {},
            prop2: {}
        }
    }
}
```

If I wanted to catch only the list of `prop1` inside `level1`, could I build a reference path with wildcards like so: `level1/*/prop1`?
I don't think this is possible, but I am asking just to confirm, since I didn't find mentions to it in the documentation.

The call to the list of `prop1`, theoretically, would look like this: `firebase.database().ref('level1/*/prop1')`.

Yes, I am trying to avoid to split those `props` into different nodes and then having to reference one to the other. Lazy programmer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved on to test it. It is not possible to use wildcards when building paths to be used to catch firebase database references. Instead, do fetch just `prop1`, the database structure has to be modified. The new structure will look like the following:

```
{
    level1 : {
        prop1level: {
            0: {prop1: {}},
            1: {prop1: {}},
            2: {prop1: {}}
        },
        prop2level: {
            0: {prop2: {}},
            1: {prop2: {}},
            2: {prop2: {}}
        }
    }
}
```

With this new database structure I am able to set different rules for the different properties.